# Determining if a matrix is square by applying QR decomposition

Tags: matrix-decomposition, least-squares

I have been solving least squares problems and I came across the following problem:

"Construct an algorithm based on the $QR$ decomposition ($A=QR$) that determines whether a square matrix is singular or not, you explicitly write your algorithm".

What I have tried is to do $QR$ and if it can check the determinant of $R$ and if it is zero the matrix A is singular.

My doubt is if what I am doing makes sense or if on the contrary there is a better way to do it(where some property of $QR$ is applied)?

Comment: You don't actually need to compute the determinant per se. You can just loop through the diagonal entries and check whether any of them are zero. Of course the determinant will work for this.

Comment: Indeed, as @Ian mentioned, computing determinant is expensive and could be largely unstable for large matrices. The same thing can be said about computing inverse of a matrix.